# Install vim with clipboard support using Macports in OS X 10.7.3

Tags: macos, vim, macports

I know that one can pass ./configure some flags to install vim with clipboard support. I want to do this via Macports.

In apt, there was a way to download a package's source without first installing it, then install it using dpkg. Is there a similar thing I can do in Macports? I'd like to have Macports download the vim source for me, and then ./configure it myself, then install it, so that Macports is aware of the installation in case I want to uninstall it for some reason.

If I can't do this via Macports, can I do it with brew? I'm trying to avoid downloading the source directly so that I can have some sort of a package manager be aware of my vim install in case I want to remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see a port's variants with `$ port variants <portname>`: Vim has (among others) `tiny`, `small`, `normal`, `big` and `huge`.

Installing Vim with `$ sudo port install vim +huge` is the most conservative way to install Vim with clipboard support via MacPorts. I honestly don't know if it's available with `+big` or `+normal` but it wouldn't take more than 10 minutes to try all these versions.

---

You use CLI tools in Mac OS X just like you use their counterparts on Linux: just like it's not self-evident that you can do `$ apt-get source vim` and you have to actually do `$ apt-get --help` to know about it (or be told about it by other people), `$ port --help` or `$ man port` would have put you in the right direction very quickly.

While it is certainly both elegant and trendy, Homebrew's list of packages is **very** small compared to MacPort's: I'm not sure migrating is the wisest choice, here. Unless you are perfectly sure that your needs are and will remain fully covered by Homebrew.

Comment: I was aware of the port variants. I didn't want the "huge" variant of vim because of all the extra things it came bundled with. However, you did answer the more pertinent question, so I'll accept your answer. Also, I'm assuming that there isn't a way to get a port's source without creating my own port? That's unfortunate.

As far as homebrew having the packages I need, I did double-check before migrating. :)

Comment: Don't assume anything, read the docs: the whole `install` process can be broken up in several steps: `fetch`, `checksum`, `configure` and so on… A simple `$ sudo port fetch vim` will download the source for you to play with. But if you are ready to do the configuration yourself, why not just using the source from vim.org directly? Also, the "brew" below installs the "huge" version as well.

Comment: I was thinking that I'd have macports manage my package after configuring it -- mainly for removing it later.

Comment: That's exactly what you'do with 0. `$ sudo port fetch vim`, 1. editing the config file, 2. `$ sudo port configure vim`, and 3. `$ sudo port install vim`. You do the configuration yourself and let MacPorts do the management.

Comment: Are you sure that +huge provides access to the clipboard? from what I see on the port file it just adds the `--with-features=huge` argument.

Comment: romainl, thanks so much for walking me through this. I won't be switching back to MacPorts, (yet) (I like how homebrew's stuff is symlinked into /usr/local/bin/, I hated having an /opt/ directory) This will definitely come handy if I ever do switch back.

Comment: @El Isra, `--with-features=huge` is a shortcut. It's a convenient way to skip typing a lot of configure options.

Comment: For my install on Big Sur, the vim +huge variant shows "-xterm_clipboard" and does not work with the clipboard.  FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

If you use brew with the duplicates vim dist it will compile with clipboard support:

`brew install https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/master/vim.rb`

Comment: What is the "duplicates vim dist"?

Comment: They duplicate software that is already provided by OSX but which are more recent or bugfix versions https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes#readme

Comment: I'm migrating to homebrew as I'm typing... :)

Comment: This is definitely the best way to do it if you don't want to include the gui with MacVim.